# Read Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, xls

I need to read the contents of a XLS file which has 10 columns and one of which contains the float vales like(10.5, 78.88).

However when I try to read the values I get values like (105, 7888), please help me in this regard with any example code or any valid solution.

Comment: You might want to update your question with the code you're currently using. (Otherwise, it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.)

Comment: Yeah. Please show some code. Also, reading an XLS file is orders of magnitude more complex than reading a CSV file. Any chance of making Excel store the data as CSV?

Comment: I am using another code and problem with this code is its not reading lines more than 40 or so, although its reading float value, could please help me, I have got the source code form here http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

Comment: @Jos you should show the code you are using to call that library.

Comment: require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
 $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("Book1.xls");
 for ($i = 2; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
          for ($j = 1; $j <= 9; $j++) {
   $column_name = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][1][$j];
   $_POST[$column_name] = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

You could try to follow the tutorial @ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/index.html to see what you are doing differently to get your current code to work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Only useful if the Excel file has been saved in the Excel 2003 XML format, rather than the traditional Excel BIFF format (.xls files) or the newer Office Open XML format (.xlsx files). From his comments, the OP is trying to read BIFF (.xls) files... your solution entails converting that to Excel 2003 XML format, he might as well convert to CSV if he needs to convert format

Comment: Script to read Excel file in php : http://allitstuff.com/read-excel-file-in-php-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPExcel that allows you to both read and write Excel file. Download it [here](https://github.com/markushausammann/PHPExcel/blob/master/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php).

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($dirpath .'/'. $fileName); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C3', 'some text here');
// Write the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($dirpath .'/'. $fileName);
```